# Boolean not showing up in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an odd issue. When a user creates a game in my app, some information from their account is stored into the game node so it can be used. Everything works well, except I have one Boolean that is, for some reason, not being passed into the database. I have a few Booleans in the database that are passed just fine, but for some reason one of them won't and I don't know why.

Here is my User constructor that is used when a user creates a game:

```
public User(String userName, int score, String HorT, String uid, String gameId, int position, boolean ready, boolean inGame) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
    this.HorT = HorT;
    this.gameId = gameId;
    this.ready = ready;
    this.position = position;
    this.inGame = inGame;
}
```

And then here is the user object being created and added to the game:

```
final User user1 = new User(userName, 0, getSide(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), gameID, 1,false, false);

FCLobbyMaker gameMaker = new FCLobbyMaker(user1, null, wager, gameID, false, false);
```

And this is what my database looks like:

[image]

I am really confused why the `inGame` Boolean is not being passed into the database, but other Booleans like `ready` are being passed. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

---

I am adding this to the database by passing `false` as the last variable in this line (creating the user)

```
final User user1 = new User(userName, 0, getSide(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), gameID, 1,false, false);
```

And then I add the user to the game by passing `user1` in this gameMaker line

```
FCLobbyMaker gameMaker = new FCLobbyMaker(user1, null, wager, gameID, false, false);
```

And then finally I add the entire gameMaker to the database using this line

```
FCGames.child(gameID).setValue(gameMaker);
```

And you can see that this is working properly because in the database picture I showed, user1 is one of the nodes in the game and it has all of the variables that I passed in `user1` except the `inGame` boolean

Comment: Does it work if you change inGame to an int instead, and use 0 and 1 to act as booleans?

Comment: can you share how are you sending the values from the code to Firebase?

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have the `gameMaker` posted above, and then I just add it to my database using this line `FCGames.child(gameID).setValue(gameMaker);` I am not sure that is exactly what you meant but I can add more to the original post if need be

Comment: @Windmill no it does not work doing that either.

Comment: yes, can you show us how you are adding it to the database? maybe you have a typo there

Comment: @GastónSaillén I added more to the bottom of the post, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: check your object model

Comment: @ZwalPyaeKyaw do you see an issue with my `user1` object?

Comment: I think you would have initialized the object earlier, but it doesn't contain `inGame` parameter. That's why I asked you to check.

Comment: @ZwalPyaeKyaw I see. My `user1` object has the inGame parameter as the last variable

Comment: You are not getting my point. At your user object,
`gameid`
`hort`
`position`
`ready`
`uid`
`username`

and in your `firebase`,

`balance`
`gameid`
`hort`
`looses`
`position`
`ready`
`uid`
`username`
`wins`

same parameters are

`balance`
`looses`
`score`
`wins`

but not `ingame`. where have you initialized them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184599/discussion-between-zwal-pyae-kyaw-and-brentb).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the entire `User` object, not just the constructor.

Comment: Please share your entire User class and please also responde with @AlexMamo